# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException Spring Configuration

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven

when i try to enable the transaction manager with an annotation in spring, i got an exception.

A code'source:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import(value = { PropertyConfiguration.class })
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    PropertyConfiguration propertyConfiguration;

    @Bean
    public Emo emo() {
        return new Emo();
    }
}
```

i got this excption:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:220)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
```

any idea?
Thanks

Comment: You're mixing Spring library versions.

Comment: Yes, this means you have JARs out of synch.  I'd rebuild your dependencies to make sure you have the right versions for Spring.

Comment: i do many times, but nothing happen. i added two dependencies: spring-aop and org.aspectj but nothing. :-(

Comment: i checked my pom.xml again and i use only one version:<org.springframework-version>4.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>